# Swift Stop System Audio

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm developing a Sleep Timer App. As soon as the timer is done, I want to stop the audio on the device. Is there any way to stop the system Sound or do I have to play a silent audio file?

I already tried this Code:

```
do {
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true) 
} catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code above? How are you testing it? Is your app playing audio at that point? Are other apps playing audio at that point?

Comment: I was playing Audio from Safari to test it, it didn't work. Because of a print() I know that the code was executed, but the audio didn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

`.playback` will only pause non-mixable sessions. If the other app has a mixable session, then it will continue. The only mode that will pause mixable sessions is `.record` (which will require that you request recording permission, even though you're not going to use it).

Comment: Sounds interesting. What is a mixable session?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616611-mixwithothers#